# How can query I the expected type of an argument from an argparse parser object?

Tags: python, argparse

I would like to determine what the expected type of a particular argument is from an `argparse.ArgumentParser` object. Is that possible?

The context is to reconstruct an `argparse.Namespace` object from string key, value pairs, however I don't know what type the values are supposed to be (I only have them as strings) and would prefer not to have to guess.

Comment: The `parser._actions` is a list of all the `Action` objects created by `add_argument` calls.  The action's `type` argument is the function that converts the input string to something else (if anything).  The default conversion is the do-nothing one - leave as a string.  `int` and `float` are the most common alternatives.  Otherwise it's a custom conversion.

Comment: Just a note.  the `type` is a function, not a "type" in some sort of formal class sense.  It doesn't necessarily convert the string to something else; it may just check the value in some way or other.

Answer (score 1):

Built-in function `type()` could be used to check argument type.

Comment: That can work when the default has the same type as the argument type (by parsing a dummy empty command line), but if the default for an argument is None, it doesn't work unfortunately. To get types for all arguments, you'd have to pass correct arguments to all None-default options, a hack I'd rather avoid.